# Recursively get parents from model with a mother_id and father_id

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a simple Family Tree Laravel application. Now I'm running in a problem due to the way I've always retrieved the parents for testing. This went with multiple queries and obviously was very inefficient.

I am using a simple table which amongst others contains the columns: id, mother_id, father_id

I've got the relationships set up as follows:

```
public function mother()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Person', mother_id');
}

public function father()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Person', 'father_id');
}
```

Now I want to recursively get both parents, and the parents of those parents etc. I found a way to do this with one parent, but then it only loads all the mothers, or all the fathers. I'm currently stuck on how to properly do this without having a new query for every set of parents.

**Update:**
If there is no proper solution to be found I might use a pivot table instead. I'd like to keep all the current entries though. Then I'd just get all the pivot entries recursively. Is the following method a proper way of handling it instead? I would then go ahead and identify the mother and father based on the gender property.

```
public function parents()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Person::class);
}

public function allParents()
{
    return $this->parents()->with('allParents');
}

//Person::find($id)->with('allParents');
```

Comment: I am afraid there is no silver bullet for your solution... take a look at how this is solved for one parent here on the mysql dba stack... http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes

Comment: @Serge I was afraid of that already. I updated my question with an alternative method. Though this does require me to modify my DB and find a way to convert the existing data to the new method.

Comment: A technique used for tree representation is more like adjacency lists... There is a good discussion here... but do some search on adjacency lists and how they are queried and I think you will get close to what you want...  http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: You could also look at a nested set pattern. https://github.com/gazsp/baum

Comment: @RossWilson Thank you for your reply. I tried it(possibly wrong), but I'm having trouble translating my existing relations to that. I've posted different question for that problem.